# slick carousel adjust height manually

Tags: slick.js, bootstrap-accordion

I have a slick-carousel that a have some accordion tabs inside.

I need to be able to react to the bootstrap accordion collapse/expansion and adjust the height of the carousel.

It adjusts with the adaptive height correctly but only once done a full rotation.

How would I go about this.

Comment: so I have established this so far.

Answer (score 0):

so have established this so far. I are actually using velocityjs for the accordion.

```
if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            toggleActivePanel.find('.content-collapse').attr('aria-expanded', false).velocity('slideUp', {
                easing: 'easeOutQuad'
            }, { complete: resize_slider() });
            $(this).attr('aria-expanded', false).removeClass('active');
        } else {
            toggleActivePanel.find('.content-collapse').attr('aria-expanded', true).velocity('slideDown', {
                easing: 'easeOutQuad'
            }, { complete: resize_slider() });
            $(this).attr('aria-expanded', true).addClass('active');
        }

function resize_slider() {
        var sliderAdaptiveHeight = function () {
            var heights = [];
            let items = $('.slick-active')
            items.each(function () {
                heights.push($(this).height());
            });
            $('.slick-list').height(Math.max.apply(null, heights));
        }
        sliderAdaptiveHeight();

        $('.slider').on('afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
            sliderAdaptiveHeight();
        });
    }
```

the resize_slider function is being triggered however the height adjustments are back to front.

ie when expanding the slick slider height retracts and when collapsing the slick slider expands.

any thoughts